# How to call startactivity or call intent from onitemclick event of listview in fragment?

Tags: android

I have a fragment that has its own layout. In the layout, there is a listview and i attached onitemclick listener that will start/open an intent when the list row is clicked. Unfortunately, I always get this error :

**Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag**

But I do not prefer to set the flag activity. I could not open the SamplePage.class

```
public class FrontPageFragment extends Fragment
{

    private ArrayList<Order> m_orders = null;
    private OrderAdapter m_adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frontpage, container, false);

        m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
        this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.name, m_orders);

        View eView=(View)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.approvedOrders);
        ListView listView=(ListView)eView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SamplePage.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", "1");
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
         });

        //bind data
        listView.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);


        return fragmentView;

    }
```

Comment: You need activity context from where you call this fragment. Instead starting new intent you can add another fragment which will be nearly the same.

Answer (score 12):

When I copied ur code I got the same error. So I changed it a little bit, and it worked. Check this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Sampleclass.class);

intent.putExtra("id", 1);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: startActivity(intent); was the key! When I used other statements such as getBaseContext.startActivity(intent); then there were errors.

Comment: In my case the first line looks like `Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Sampleclass.class);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FrontPageFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I solve my problem with your solution, thanks! I'm trying to start NewsDetailActivity activity inside `onItemClick()` inner class' method of NewsActivity activity with the following code: 
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewsDetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra("newsId", "1");
NewsActivity.this.startActivity(i);