# Slidingmenu navigation nothing happen

Tags: java, android, arrays, slidingmenu

I'me trying to write an sliding menu following this tutorial http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.it/2013/05/android-sliding-menu-like.html
It's ok and i have my list of items but i want that clicking on the item i can open an activity. So i try to write in the fragment this:

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                switch (arg2) { 
                case 0:     
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), HomeActivity.class); 
                    i.putExtra("CPU Statistics", "0"); MenuFragment.this.startActivity(i);         
                break;
                case 5:

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), settings.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);

                }
            }
```

the menu it's in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="marray">
        <item>Chart</item>
        <item>settings</item>
    </string-array>
```

But nothing happen when i click the items. Something's wrong?

Comment: why do you use getActivity().startActivity(intent) instead of just startActivity(intent)

Comment: anyway doesn't change. :( if i click the activities not opens.

Comment: I would also try using getApplicationContext() or ClassName.this instead of getActivity()...

Comment: if that doesnt help try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177633/how-to-call-startactivity-or-call-intent-from-onitemclick-event-of-listview-in-f

Comment: This code is in a fragment class..doesn't work the getApplicationContext or ClassName.this

Comment: check out the link i found i think thats the answer you need...

Comment: edited the post.. Nothing change(look at the first condition)

Comment: the first item it's the array 0 right? starts from 0?

Comment: the first item in an array is 0 yes unless you force otherwise...

Comment: why?it's to differences from the others not?

Comment: I actually dont know why it doesnt work... seems to me like it should... could you post more code? or are you getting anything in the LogCat? something i can see? did you step by step debug it to see exactly where it stops and what happens when the intents occure?