# Start Activities from onItemClick of ListView in fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

So I have two fragments linking to layout files which display ListViews. The ListViews are defined in the xml and have entries from a string array. I want to click on items in the ListView and open new activities. There are 8 items in one ListView and 9 in the other. In the onItemClick code, how do I create intents to start activities based on the item clicked? I will create 1 class per item as its own activity. How can I start the activities in the classes via intents inside the onItemClick methods of this code?

```
class CommunityFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.community_fragment, container, false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.communityListView);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
class ResourcesFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resources_fragment, container, false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.resourcesListView);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177633/how-to-call-startactivity-or-call-intent-from-onitemclick-event-of-listview-in-f  see this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make switch statement for each items click and open activities accordingly as below:

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     int itm=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                switch (itm) {
                case 0:
                Toast.makeText(m_context, "Position Zero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                  Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent1);
                              break;
                case 2:
                          //..............................

        }
    });
```

Comment: @GrlsHu   What's wrong with these sequence of instructions: `lv.setOnItemClickListener(null);`
 `lv.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListerner(){@Override  onItemClick(...){...}});`   It can't work. I though the events can be registered to the `Listener`.

Comment: @Stallman By writing `lv.setOnItemClickListener(null);` its indicating that you have not registered your listview to any listener. You must have to implement a listener first accordingly and then you can apply it to view. You can not pass null value.

Answer (score 2):

Implement your  `OnItemClickListener()` like below

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), nextactivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

on Item Click you will get Position based on position you can start fragment

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
       switch(position) {
        case CONST_FRAGMENT_1 :
                  //Start fragment 1
            ...
            ...
       }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one Generic solution can be ..

Create an array of items that hold class name of activity you want to open ..
 like ..

```
Class[] activityArray = new Class[numberOfItemsInListView];
            activityArray[0] = Activity1.class;
```

//add all activities like that..............

now on ListView onItemCLick :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(CommunityFragment.this.getActivity(), activityArray[postion]);
                    CommunityFragment.this.getActivity.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to start next intent in your onItemClickListener:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), nextactivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following code help you.

```
public class PdfListViewFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    Activity rootView;
    Activity context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf_list_view, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[]{"Android List View",
                "Adapter implementation",
                "Simple List View In Android",
                "Create List View Android",
                "Android Example",
                "List View Source Code",
                "List View Array Adapter",
                "Android Example List View"
        };

        // Define a new Adapter
        // First parameter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListItemActivity1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListItemActivity2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListItemActivity1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 3) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListItemActivity2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 4) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListItemActivity1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 5) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListItemActivity2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 6) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListItemActivity1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 7) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListItemActivity2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }


                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert

                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("XYZ");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an adapter to display the items in a list, it is important to differentiate the following:

**The ID of the list `AdapterView#getId()` is different than the ID of the items in the list `ArrayAdapter<String>#getId()`, because the view of the list contains the views of the elements.**

Suppose an example where you are going to launch activities with user roles. You will have to do the transformation for your particular case.

```
public class SignInFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    //TODO: Declare constants (GUEST, HOST, EMPLOYEE...)    

    private ArrayAdapter<String> userRolesAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in, container, false);

//            ListView Instance
        ListView userRolesList = root.findViewById(R.id.user_roles_list);

        String[] userRoles = {
                GUEST,
                HOST,
                EMPLOYEE
        };

//            Initialize the adapter
        userRolesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                userRoles
        );

//            Link to the list with the adapter. This reference starts the process of filling the list.
        userRolesList.setAdapter(userRolesAdapter);

//            Events
        userRolesList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return root;
    }

    /**
     * @param adapterView: View using the adapter from the list
     * @param view: View of the item that has been pressed
     * @param i: Refers to the position of the item that the adapter handles
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if (adapterView.getId() == R.id.user_roles_list) {

//              Obtain the item pressed on the adapter with the entry position
            String currentUserRol = userRolesAdapter.getItem(i);

            assert currentUserRol != null;
            switch (currentUserRol) {
                case GUEST:
                    startActivity(Host.class);
                    break;
                case HOST:
                    startActivity(Host.class);
                    break;
                case EMPLOYEE:
                    startActivity(Employee.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d("Error", "The activity passed as an argument to startActivity() does not exist");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * PRECONDITION: The class given as an argument exists.
     */
    public void startActivity(Class<?> cls) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), cls);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Best :)