# List view with onItemClickListner was not working

Tags: android, android-listview

**OnItemClickListner** is not working any one help me ,I want click list item each item goes to next activity

**java** class

```
 public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    private ListAdapter mAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
    private ListView listview;


     @Override

         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout_one, container, false);

             prepareList();        
            mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), listCountry, listFlag);
            //Missed code to here
            listview = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_listView);
            listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);


            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                }

            });

             return rootView;

         }

     public void prepareList()
        {
            listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();

            listCountry.add("India");
            listCountry.add("USA");
            listCountry.add("Canada");
            listCountry.add("AUS");



            listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.india);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.usa);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.canada);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.aus);

        }

}
```

Comment: is it giving some error??

Comment: *OnItemClickListner was not working...* because there is no code in `onItemClick` method's body ...

Answer (score 2):

Little mistake, Please Add your code with in `onItemClick` method

**In here Showing Toast Message . And Demo code for New Activity Launch**

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              // Add your staff here 
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Listview Click"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Your_Desise.class);
             startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
```

Try this way .I am sure it will helps you .

> [Listview , open new activity onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660126/listview-open-new-activity-onclick)
>
> [Start Activities from onItemClick of ListView in fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165253/start-activities-from-onitemclick-of-listview-in-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

you must need to call `AdapterView` onItemClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Click" +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```